# knitr markdown to knitr latex or vice versa

Tags: github, workflow, knitr

I am writing an economics paper and using the [RopenSci workflow](http://ropensci.org/) (Rstudio, Github, knitr).

Since I need a draft PDF, I am using knitr. However I am also editing the README.md file to describe the project on github.

My question is whether it is easiest to go from a latex knitr file to a markdown knitr file, or the other way around?

Comment: I would vote on the "other way around" as you can easily convert your markdown file to pdf with `pandoc`

Comment: I agree with @daroczig -- if you need a draft PDF, install pandoc and run `pandoc -o foo.pdf foo.md` where `foo.md` is `knitr`'s output from `foo.Rmd`.

Comment: thanks you for the comments, ideally you would go from .Rmd to Rnw, is there any way to do this?

Comment: @bquast I think it is much better to go from .md to .tex than from .Rmd to .Rnw, given the power of pandoc.

Comment: @Yihui I guess my problem with this is that this leaves environments such as `Shaded` and `Highlighting` undefined. When going from .Rmd to .Rnw the knitting of the .Rnw file would take care of this, right?

Comment: I guess, it would be ideal if pandoc supported knitr, but since it doesn't this will work fine.

Comment: @bquast You need the `--standalone` option (or `-s` for short), e.g. `pandoc -s -o foo.pdf foo.md`; by default the tex output does not include the preamble; see http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html